# Getting Error when importing format_suffix_patterns from Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework, python-3.6, django-2.2

I am learning `Django Rest Framework`.
I used `format_suffix_patterns` to support suffixes in the `Urls`
Everything was fine, till suddenly I started getting error

```
_frozen_importlib._DeadlockError: deadlock detected by _ModuleLock('django.test.signals') at 1367726740816
```

and

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

Even on importing '`format_suffix_patterns`' with

```
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
```

gives the error.

But just before I started using viewsets there was no problem.

I tried removing the old env and creating a new env
Deleting the pycache and retrying

**This is the include that is creating the error**

```
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
```

**The full error**

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\checks.py", line 79, in check_dependencies
    for engine in engines.all():
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 90, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 25, in __init__
    options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 108, in get_installed_libraries
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 121, in get_package_libraries
    module = import_module(entry[1])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\templatetags\rest_framework.py", line 15, in <module>
    from rest_framework.renderers import HTMLFormRenderer
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\renderers.py", line 20, in <module>
    from django.test.client import encode_multipart
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 23, in <module>
    from django.test import signals
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 149, in __enter__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 94, in acquire
_frozen_importlib._DeadlockError: deadlock detected by _ModuleLock('django.test.signals') at 1367726740816

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Web Development/messmanager/app_old/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:/Web Development/messmanager/app_old/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 585, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 570, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 288, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 294, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 334, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 350, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 249, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 103, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "E:\Web Development\messmanager\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 136, in iter_modules_and_files
    if not path.exists():
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\pathlib.py", line 1334, in exists
    self.stat()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\pathlib.py", line 1156, in stat
    return self._accessor.stat(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\pathlib.py", line 387, in wrapped
    return strfunc(str(pathobj), *args)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

Comment: Maybe old pyc causing issues.  Try the following

- Delete all the .pyc files in the project with this command: `find . -regex '*.pyc' -delete`

- Deactivate the virtual environment and reactivate it.

Comment: How can I do it in windows?

Answer (score 1):

Even I was facing same error.

I commented below code and it worked for me.

```
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

Comment: The problem is not easily reproducible, which makes this bug so hard to combat. It tends to happen "sometimes" and mainly while running Django in a multi-pod Kubernetes on the same node

Comment: @omkar where should I add these line in the API ie in Views, Model or Serializers.